# How to make little vibrate like apps store install button action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vibration

I am trying to make little vibrate alert like, when we press install button in apps store. I am using below code, but this is making long vibration, I need exact same like app store. Many apps using this feature in many ways like when long press in collection view cell they gave this vibrate.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved same requirement in my app using below code. I am sure it will work for you.

**iOS 10 and Above you can achieved using new public API for handling haptic feedback: `UIFeedbackGenerator`**

```
let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
generator.notificationOccurred(.error)
generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
generator.notificationOccurred(.warning)

// Light
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
generator.impactOccurred()

// Medium
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
generator.impactOccurred()

// Heavy
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.impactOccurred()

// Update: Call this method for vibration
// Update: it is mandetory method for vibration

generator.prepare()
```

**For iOS 9 and older, you could use AudioToolBox.**

```
import AudioToolbox

private let isDevice = TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR == 0

func vibrate() {
    if isDevice {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am testing on my iPhone X, iPhone 6S, 6S plus. But not working. Please help.

Comment: Still no luck. I can't understand why this code is not working!! I am also using appcoda code. But same result.

Comment: I used it.  @IBAction func onePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
        generator.impactOccurred()
        generator.prepare()
    } . But not working.

Comment: @Saad All works for me, check your devices or something

Comment: @Hitesh UIFeedbackGenerator working on only iPhone 7.  Which device r u using? For iPhone 6S plus or iPhone X using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate), but this is not similar like UIFeedbackGenerator. I need this effect on iphone 6S plus.

Comment: In iPhoneX the `generator.notificationOccurred(.success)` is exactly similar to the install feedback after press install in AppStore, for others iPhone (iPhone 6s) the tapticsfeedback is older version and might result is incorrect vibration

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the taptic feedback engine, whose functionality is abstracted to the [`UIFeedbackGenerator` class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator).